# Getting cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'AZURE_TRACING_DISABLED')

Tags: angular, azure-blob-storage

Im using @azure/storage-blob npm library,
Using BlobServiceCLient to get the list of containers with method listContainers()

after the call getting error

cannot read properties of undefined  (reading 'AZURE_TRACING_DISABLED')

```
const connectionString = `BlobEndpoint=${environment.SAS_URL};SharedAccessSignature=${environment.SAS}`    
this.blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(connectionString);
```

called the get container using below code

```
async listCointainer(){   
  let containers = []    
  let iter = this.blobServiceClient.listContainers()    
  let containerItems = await iter.next()    
  while(!containerItems.done){      
   containers.push(containerItems.value.name)      
   containerItems = await iter.next()    }    
   console.log(containers);  }
```

Comment: Could you please add the code what you have tried?

Comment: @Venkatesan I have added the code which I did

Comment: Based on the error can you please check if this helps "https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues/10205"

Answer (score 0):

Adding the below code to pollyfills.ts worked for me

```
(window as any).AZURE_TRACING_DISABLED = true;
```